# Prove the following by changing the order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

This question is from my university paper:

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} x e^{\frac{-x^2}{y}}\; dy\;dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

I tried using **DUIS** method but integration is getting complicated

## $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} x e^{\frac{-x^2}{y}}\; dy$

## $ \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{d}{dx} x e^{\frac{-x^2}{y}}\; dy $
$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{e^{-x^2}(1-2x^2)}{y}\; dy $ 
$ \hspace{75px}= e^{(-x^2)} (1 - 2 x^2) \{\log(x)-\log(0)\}$
$ \hspace{75px}= e^{(-x^2)} (1 - 2 x^2)\;\log(x)$
$\int \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \int{e^{(-x^2)} (1 - 2 x^2)\;\log(x) \;dx} $

First we must integrate with respect to $y$ and that's where I'm getting stuck.
Is there any other method to solve this? What's going wrong?

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with the DUIS method, but I do notice that $y$ has mysteriously disappeared when you partially differentiated the integrand with respect to $x$. Also, $\log(0) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do what is written in your question's title?:

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^x xe^{-x^2/y}\,dy\,dx=\int_0^\infty\int_y^\infty xe^{-x^2/y}\,dx\,dy=\int_0^\infty\left.\left(-\frac y2\right)e^{-x^2/y}\right|_y^\infty dy=$$

$$=-\frac12\int_0^\infty y\left(0-e^{-y}\right)\,dy=\frac12\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy=\left.\frac12\left[-ye^{-y}\right]\right|_0^\infty+\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy=$$

$$\left.\frac12\left(-e^{-y}\right)\right|_0^\infty=\frac12$$